# Laravel Site Appears Blank After Chmod -R 755

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, permissions

I was uploading changes to a Laravel site hosted on AWS EC2. I had to change the permissions of the folder to allow me to upload them via FTP. I ran the command,
`sudo chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu /var/www/html`
then
`sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/html`
I uploaded the files to the server and they uploaded fine but then I noticed that the site just appears blank. I first noticed just the pages effected by my changes but then the whole site appeared blank.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change your storage folder and its subfolders to 777 and the rest folders to 755 and files to 644.

This question has been answered many times already. It is a duplicate.